Black screen issue in ubuntu 22.04 lts after charging is removed
My dell laptop having ubuntu 22.04 lts shows black screen without cursor when the charging is removed and sometimes it shows black screen when being charged if anyone have any clue how to fix this issue kindly comment down.i will be appreciated.
